# Spring MVC Configuring Data Source Bean (Spring 3.0,Hibernate,Apache Tomcat, Netbeans)

Tags: spring, apache, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I’m trying to run/setup a simple Spring MVC 3 + Hibernate + Apache Tomcat 7.0, using NetBeans 7.1  as a development environment.

Netbeans comes with prepackaged Spring and Hibernate files/jars/dependecies already setup in the right directory structure.

In order to setup the data source bean in applicationContext I had 2 choices

---

**Variation #1** 
(using  data source class=”org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource” which was prepackaged data source with NetBeans for Spring development)

Snippet from applicationContext.xml

```
<!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->  
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"    
destroy-method="close"    p:driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"    
p:jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourmarketnet"   
p:user="root"    
p:password="arya6678"   
p:acquireIncrement="5"    
p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"    
p:maxPoolSize="100"    
p:maxStatements="50"    
p:minPoolSize="10" /> 
<!-- Declare the Hibernate SessionFactory for retrieving Hibernate sessions -->   
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">    
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>    
<property name="configLocation" ref="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>    
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.yourmarketnet.*" />
</bean>
```

**Variation 2, Error result: 
My Application fails to run, Apache Tomcat Log:**

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'acquireIncrement' of bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]: Bean property 'acquireIncrement' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'acquireIncrement' of bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]: Bean property 'acquireIncrement' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1052)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:921)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)

**Variation #2**
(using data source class=” org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource”)
Then I decided to download Apache Commons dbcp jar , and I added the “commons-dbcp-1.4.jar” to my project.

Snippet from applicationContext.xml

```
<!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->  
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"    
destroy-method="close"    p:driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"    
p:jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourmarketnet"   
p:user="root"    
p:password="arya6678"   
p:acquireIncrement="5"    
p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"    
p:maxPoolSize="100"    
p:maxStatements="50"    
p:minPoolSize="10" /> 
<!-- Declare the Hibernate SessionFactory for retrieving Hibernate sessions -->   
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">    
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>    
<property name="configLocation" ref="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>    
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.yourmarketnet.*" />
</bean>
```

---

**Variation 2, Error result: 
My Application fails to run, Apache Tomcat Log:**

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'acquireIncrement' of bean class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]: Bean property 'acquireIncrement' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'acquireIncrement' of bean class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]: Bean property 'acquireIncrement' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1052)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:921)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    ... 21 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The p namespace (`p:user`, `p:password`, `p:acquireIncrement`) is used to set properties on your java beans. It looks like you are trying to set the `acquireIncrement` property on the `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` and `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource` classes. According to the documentation for these classes ([Apache Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html) and [Spring's Data Source](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html)), neither of these have a setter method for this property which is why you see the NotWritablePropertyException in your stacktrace.

Check out the [Spring's docs regarding the p-namespace](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-p-namespace) about configuration.

If I were choosing, I would pick Apache's data base connection pool (dbcp). Simple & well used.

Comment: Thank you are right, I consulted the Spring docs regarding p-namespace and it seems, some of my property names were wrong. Correct xml bean code is below: `<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myWebAppDb" p:username="root" p:password="pass" p:maxActive="0" p:initialSize="50"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a particular question, or you just don't understand the errors? The messages are pretty clear: acquireIncrement isn't a property on the classes you're trying to set it on. I believe that property is from the C3P0 connection pool.

Comment: Yes the property names were for C3P0 driver setup, instead of Apache BasicDataSource driver , below is the correct xml that I used `<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"    
destroy-method="close"    p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"    
p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myWebAppDb"   
p:username="root"    
p:password="pass"    
p:maxActive="0"    
p:initialSize="50"/>`

Comment: P.S. Don't use DriverManagerDataSource except for testing.