# Error creating bean with name 'accountController'

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

So, we have finally managed to update our Spring Framework from version `3.2` to `4.2.25`. After some painful processes I am now stuck at this exception: `Error creating bean with name 'accountController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`.

**web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring/servlet-security.xml
        </param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml,
                /WEB-INF/spring/servlet-security.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
</web-app>
```

**jdbc-context.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        ">

<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring/spring.properties" />

<!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />   

<!-- Declare a transaction manager -->
<!-- See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />

<!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->   
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
            destroy-method="close"
            p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
            p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
            p:user="${app.jdbc.username}"
            p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
            p:acquireIncrement="1"
            p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
            p:maxPoolSize="247"
            p:maxStatements="100"
            p:minPoolSize="1" />    

<bean id="dataSourceSlave" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
            destroy-method="close"
            p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
            p:jdbcUrl="${app.slave.jdbc.url}"
            p:user="${app.slave.jdbc.username}"
            p:password="${app.slave.jdbc.password}"
            p:acquireIncrement="1"
            p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
            p:maxPoolSize="247"
            p:maxStatements="100"
            p:minPoolSize="1" />
```

And a full exception **printStack()**:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'accountController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'accountService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'friendService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'agentProfileService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'screenNameService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'exceptionService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'mailService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'emailNotificationService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'sportProfileService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'countryService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceSlave' defined in 
    ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/jdbc-context.xml]:
        Error setting property values; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException:
    Invalid property 'acquireIncrement' of bean class
    [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]:
    Bean property 'acquireIncrement' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.
    Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5068)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1259)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1998)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Not sure if relevant: I am using `javax.servlet-api-3.1`.

And now **AccountService.java**:

```
@Service("accountService")
@Transactional
public class AccountService
{
protected static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(AccountService.class);
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
private SimpleJdbcInsert jdbcInviteInsert;
private SimpleJdbcInsert jdbcChallengeInsert;
private SimpleJdbcInsert jdbcPostitInsert;
private SimpleJdbcInsert jdbcPreferenceInsert;

@Resource(name = "dataSource")
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
{
    this.jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    this.jdbcInviteInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource).withTableName("invite_contact").usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");
    this.jdbcChallengeInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource).withTableName("challenge").usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");
    this.jdbcPreferenceInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource).withTableName("preference").usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");
    this.jdbcPostitInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource).withTableName("account_postit");
}

// super-awesome-revolutionary code

}
```

If there is any additional information I should provide, please let me know :)

Comment: formatting the error message makes it a little simpler to see what happens (`acquireIncrement="1"` cannot be applied to a `DriverManagerDataSource` because there is no setter for such a property)

Comment: Have a look at this question, it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710020/spring-mvc-configuring-data-source-bean-spring-3-0-hibernate-apache-tomcat-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DriverManagerDataSurce does not provide pooling capabilities. It does not define the properties acquireIncrement ,idleConnectionTestPeriod,     maxPoolSize ,maxStatements and minPoolSize.

Either remove these properties or use a datasource that supports pooling eg apache commons-dbcp BasicDataSource. DriverManagerDataSurce is not recommed for use in production systems. Its for testing purposes.

For example

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. in the end I end up using the following class: `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource`. It also supports pooling.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is

No bean named 'dataSourceSlave' is defined

Seems like somewhere inside service you reference it by this name, while the datasource bean is created with name 'dataSource'.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to remove the comments when I tried something. Files jdbc-context.xml and exception trace have been updated in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Check your servlet-context.xml to see if you are scanning the package where your controller are and then check if you have something like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your/package/path/controllers"/>
```

your/package/path/controllers is where your controller class are living.

Comment: hmm, shouldnt `<context:component-scan base-package="your/package/"/>` do the trick for all its subdirectories?

Comment: The basic idea is to scan the package where the controllers are, offcourse you can also set to scan all the packages in your project to find the controllers

Comment: right, because I had scanned the whole package while getting this error. So I don't think this is the case :/